# Activity's onPause and onResume being called after starting, for no reason

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have a very simple activity that logs a message whenever one of the lifecycle methods is called.

This is my onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("HELP ME");
    ll.addView(tv);
    setContentView(ll);
    Log.i(TAG, "CREATE");
}
```

And this is the resulting logcat without any user input:

```
    07-23 16:14:12.057: I/sigh(12196): CREATE
    07-23 16:14:12.067: I/sigh(12196): START
    07-23 16:14:12.067: I/sigh(12196): RESUME
    07-23 16:14:13.657: I/sigh(12196): PAUSE
    07-23 16:14:13.687: I/sigh(12196): RESUME
    07-23 16:14:14.167: I/sigh(12196): PAUSE
    07-23 16:14:14.177: I/sigh(12196): RESUME
```

Why does my app pause and resume a few times after being launched?

This behavior only occurs when I run it from Eclipse. Subsequently launches of the app from the phone itself do not exhibit the aberrant pause/resume. Does anyone have a clue as to what's happening?

**UPDATE:**

Seems like it's only happening for my phone, a Nexus 5 running 4.4.4. Doesn't happen on Samsung GS3/5 and Nexus 4. Weird.

Comment: Hi, I know this question is old, but... did you solved this issue? Do you know why onPause and OnResume are fired?

Comment: No, I didn't find out why they get called repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and its not behaving as funny. I think you have an issue in the background, memory issue or something that is pausing your activity without your knowledge.

Comment: Seems like it's only happening for my phone, a Nexus 5 running 4.4.4. Doesn't happen on Samsung GS3/5 and Nexus 4. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

when the screen brightness dimmed activity go to onPause when you touch it again it resumed.